# PAT typealias is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

In trying to subclass my base class that conforms to a PAT, I get this compiler warning:

> 'MyType' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

in my code as shown below:

```
protocol DataSourceProtocol {
    associatedtype MyType
    func get () -> MyType
}

class AnyDataSource: DataSourceProtocol {
    typealias MyType = EntityProtocol
    func get() -> MyType { fatalError("No implementation") }
}

class DataSource_A<T: EntityProtocol & DataSource_A_Compatible>: AnyDataSource {
    typealias MyType = T
    override func get() -> MyType { // <-- 'MyType' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
        return T()
    }
}

class DataSource_B<T: EntityProtocol & DataSource_B_Compatible>: AnyDataSource {
    override func get() -> MyType {
        return T()
    }
}
```

I am trying to  override the method `get() -> MyType` so that the `DataSource_A` instance method returns a specialized type T, hence `typealias MyType = T`

If I change the `DataSource_A` method to `override func get -> T`, the compiler says that the function does not override any method in its superclass.

In `DataSource_B`, the overridden method is called but provides no type information for type `T` because the caller receives type `EntityProtocol` which is not sufficient.

If I remove the function declaration in `DataSourceProtocol` and in the base class `AnyDataSource`, and simply declare it in the subclass, it works fine, but I want to make the method's implementation mandatory for any subclass of `AnyDataSource`.

Why can't I specify that the overridden method returns an object of type T by changing the value of `MyType` in the subclass?

Comment: What do you want the calling code for this to look like? What caller could make use of of either DataSourceProtocol or AnyDataSource without knowing that they have specifically DataSource_A or DataSource_B? Start with that code, and work your way to the protocols. Mixing PAT with class inheritance like this is a misuse of both and it will fight you. You seem to be trying to make a PAT into an abstract class, which is not what it is, or what it's for. You may be able to force this to compile with some more layers, but instead go back to the caller and see what problem you're solving.

Comment: "I want to make the method's implementation mandatory for any subclass of AnyDataSource." That's impossible in Swift today. Instead you generally want to use a protocol *and not an inherited class*. By using a protocol, you can require implementation by conforming types. You cannot do that with class inheritance. There are no abstract classes in Swift today.

Comment: Yikes! I wish I had seen this earlier. I'm revisiting this whole problem again and I will update my question soon. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make the method's implementation mandatory for any subclass
>   of AnyDataSource.

The way to express that is to make `AnyDataSource` generic.

```swift
class AnyDataSource<Entity: EntityProtocol>: DataSourceProtocol {
  func get() -> Entity { .init() }
}

class DataSource_A<Entity: EntityProtocol & DataSource_A_Compatible>: AnyDataSource<Entity> {
  // override if needed
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Jessy. This is the route I am following now...